# react-bootstrap navbar not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a navbar using react-bootstrap, but when I render it I get this:
[image]

I'm not getting any error messages, and I can't find any documentation explaining what I've got, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

This is the code I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/';

const Toolbar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar staticTop collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="test">Brandname Goes Here</a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1}>Contact Us</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2}>About Us</NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default Toolbar;
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't imported bootstrap.css in your project

Comment: have you installed `react-bootstrap` using npm?

Comment: Yes, I did install react-bootstrap via npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to [react-bootsrap getting started tab](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html)

and copy the link under the `<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->` description into your `index.html` `<head>` tag, and if you installed `react-bootstrap` using `npm`, then you can import the navbar like so: 
`import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you haven't imported `bootstrap.min.css`. Import it in your `index.html` as follows.

```
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

I cannot recommend to use something like `import 'react-bootstrap/*/*.css'` because I am not sure which framework and which loaders(eg: webpack) you are using.